# How to change file permission from Ubuntu wubi install

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux. I have a WUBI installation within Windows 7.

The issue I am having is that I can't seem to modify Windows files from Ubuntu. I can access and see all the files and folders but I can't for example make a new folder in the Windows files/folders (Permission Denied) but I can save documents, etc. to existing folders.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The partition where you install ubuntu is inside windows partition which is your host and it uses ntfs file system. So, you can't use chown, chmod and chgrp command to change the file permission.

Don't be dis-hearted just change one line in the file */etc/default/grub*

> From :- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>
> To :-  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootflags=umask=002,uid=1000,gid=1000 quiet splash"

After you make the changes save the file, you need to run

> sudo update-grub

afterwards to update /boot/grub/grub.cfg

**WARNING:**
These changes give you full access to all your files on your host, including system files and it is very very dangerous, so make sure to stay away from system folders ie. your windows system and only try this when you really really need to

*For reference you may visit [Changing file permission on host in Wubi](http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/changing-file-permission-on-host-in-wubi/) &  [How to change file permissions of host in Wubi?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657964)*