# Not enough space on hard drive for tf2

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

I'm fairly new to Linux and Ubuntu, and I recently wanted to install TF2 on Ubuntu. When I tried to install it through Steam it said TF2 was about 11GB and I there was only 2GB available so I couldn't install it.

So I checked my harddrive and my external one I was running Ubuntu on, the external one had at least 400 Gigabytes free and the other one had about 180.

What's going on? and How do I fix it?

Output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0 3.9G 1.1G 2.6G 30% /
udev 1.9G 4.0K 1.9G 1% /dev
tmpfs 752M 908K 751M 1% /run
none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
none 1.9G 868K 1.9G 1% /run/shm
none 100M 56K 100M 1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1 466G 20G 446G 5% /host
/dev/loop1 3.9G 2.1G 1.6G 58% /usr
/dev/loop2 3.9G 840M 2.9G 23% /home
/dev/sda3 454G 286G 168G 64% /media/isaac/Acer
```

---

So I tried adding a library folder in `/media/isaac/Acer` but this error came up in steam:

> "New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions"

I have never seen this error before and I did a bit of research about it and I still have no idea how to fix it. A bit of information I don't know if this helps but I think (it might be FAT 32, neeed to double check) I'm running Ubuntu off a NTFS External hard drive.

Comment: Please post the output of `df -h` in a terminal to see how space is allocated between partitions.

Answer (score 4):

What you probably want to try is tell steam to set-up a different install directory for your games. You can do this fairly easy by going to: 
Settings->Downloads+Cloud->Steam Library Folders->Add Library folder.

After doing this every game you install will ask you what library folder to install into. Just select one that has plenty of space and that should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not crazy about this idea.  There's got to be a way to take some disc space from `/host` and give it to `/home`.  Say, 200GB or so.

Comment: @Webnet I must admit I'm not sure how to do that, but my initial guess would be a simpel symbolic link. Make the folder it links to have the required executable rights and that should be it, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the number of `loop` mounts, I'm guessing this is a Ubuntu-in-Windows wubi installation?

Steam by default is installed in your `/home` partition (in `/home/USERNAME/.local/share/Steam` - files and folders starting with a dot are hidden, use `View->Show Hidden Files` to see them). This is only a 4GB partition so no room for TF2.

You can create additional steam libraries or move the whole installation to another partition. See the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226884/how-do-i-use-a-different-drive-as-an-installation-location-for-steam/).

I think (but am not certain) that you cannot use a FAT32 partition for Steam, since FAT32 has a maximum file size of 4GB and game installations generally require larger files.

It is possible to make the `/host` disk (presumably your windows `C:` drive) [writable to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195464/how-to-change-file-permission-from-ubuntu-wubi-install), **but not recommended, since this allows you to accidentally damage your windows installation**.