# changing default download path/drive

Tags: partitioning, games, steam

I just want to make new files/games/whatever to another drive I have formatted in Linux to use for my Steam games and other downloaded items. I try to add this drive and I am told that drive must be empty in order to be used. The only file that seems to be in the partitioned section is a "lost+found" file...which I am not permitted to remove. Why does Linux make file creation/manipulation so difficult? (<---obviously frustrated ignorance talking) Any help would be appreciated. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to use another drive to download to. As asked...I edited the original post to include the version and this:

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  2.6M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5  317G   18G  283G   6% /
tmpfs            16G   59M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop2       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1026
/dev/loop3      244M  244M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/39
/dev/loop4       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1081
/dev/sdc1       229G   61M  217G   1% /mnt/21d5002c-d1dc-4635-aad4-871cd04aa4ac
/dev/loop5      242M  242M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop6      102M  102M     0 100% /snap/mc-installer/568
/dev/nvme0n1p2   96M   31M   66M  32% /boot/efi
/dev/loop8       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop7      102M  102M     0 100% /snap/mc-installer/569
/dev/loop9       51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop11      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12883
/dev/loop10     165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop12      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/loop13     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop14      52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop15     163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop16     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop17      65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
tmpfs           3.2G   20K  3.2G   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           3.2G   40K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000

Hope this helps. The drive I am trying to use is /dev/sdc

Comment: A storage device with only `lost+found` *is* empty. Can you [edit] your question to include: (1) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (2) the output of `df -h` (3) which device you are trying to save the data on. This will make it more likely that you receive a solution 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change where Steam installs games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260288/how-can-i-change-where-steam-installs-games)

Comment: Create a folder, add it to the Steam Library folders. That's how it works with Steam. Of course make sure your user has write permissions there.

Comment: Also [Change the default Downloads directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60161/change-the-default-downloads-directory). Old, but at least one answer is still correct.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option to change your default download directory would be to delete your current Downloads folder and then put a symbolic link in place that redirects to your new drive.

**Procedure with GUI**

With the file manager, proceed as following:

1. Delete "Downloads"
2. Create a symbolic link named "Downloads", that links to your other drive.

Specific instructions:

1. Open Files in your home folder
2. Open another Files window in the folder where your new Downloads folder is present.
3. Drag the Downloads folder in your second pane (maybe it has a different name) to the first pane while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Release the mouse button: that creates a symbolic link (you can tell by the arrow over the icon) named like the folder you are linking to.
4. If needed (i.e. your original folder has another name), rename the link to "Downloads".

Because of Step 1, your new Downloads link will not have a special status: you can tell because the folder icon does not contain an extra symbol (a downward arrow in case of Downloads). So you need to restore that editing a configuration file. That would *not* have been necessary if you would have done the operation through terminal commands.

1. Make sure "Show hidden files" is on in Files
2. Find the file "user-dirs.dirs". It will be in the hidden `.config` folder in your home directory
3. Open the file with a text editor and make sure there is a line for the Downloads folder reading like: `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"`
4. Save the file and close the editor.